# Can't access default user settings panel in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason when I access my settings I only get my user settings.json file. I don't get the double pane with the list of defaults on the left side along with the search at the top. Is there a way to get that back or access it directly?

My VSCode Insiders Settings
[image: VSCode Insiders Settings]

VSCode working default settings. How can I get this back in my Insiders version? 
[image: VSCode Default Settings]

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this setting changed to:

```
    "workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true
```

`True` is the default but perhaps it got changed.

Comment: Ah yeah turns out they are changing the default. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/64932